# How to insert all the rows with project name that not in table A to table A from table B

Tags: sql

Sorry for bad title, don't know how to phrase my question well.
Right now I have two table:

Table A:

```
GUID         Project   State
1####        A ###     Active
2####        B ###     Active
3####        C ###     Active
4####        D ###     Active
```

table B is resource table, there are a few columns, and one column is also Project, the thing I wanna do is:

If there is a project in table B that is not in table A, add it to table A and give it GUID and Inactive state.

But I'm not sure how to implement this, tried several insert into select, doesn't work, suppose I need to use exist condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NOT IN and a sub-query.  Like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (....)
   SELECT
     ....
   FROM TableB 
   WHERE Project NOT IN (SELECT Project FROM TableA)
```

This can also be done with a left join like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (....)
   SELECT
     ....
   FROM TableB B
   LEFT JOIN TableA A ON B.Project = A.Project
   WHERE A.Project IS NULL
```

You can see how good your server software is by checking the execution plans are the same for both of these queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT some_way_to_get_guid(), b.project, 'inactive' FROM B
WHERE b.project NOT IN (SELECT project FROM A);
```

The WHERE clause is what is called an **anti-semijoin**.

Comment: (Hogan beat me to it.)

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - you comment about "anti-semijoin" made me put in the join example.